# Adding views to PagerAdapter too slow

Tags: java, android

My method  add views to `PagerAdapter`:

```
public void initdata() {
    for(int i = 0;i<=1189;i++){
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.testss,null);
    tx = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txts);
    tx.setText(textseries[i]));
    pageList.add(tx);}
 }
```

My `pagerAdapter`:

```
@Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        container.addView(pageList.get(position));
        return pageList.get(position);}
```

it takes 5~6 sec add views to `PagerAdapter` , but the `TextView` is just change it's content,how to avoid call view method so much times ?

Comment: your for loop will loop1189 times, why you set this?

Comment: I have 1189 pages. but its just change different text's content.

Comment: i don't want to be rude but what the your loop does xD

Comment: 1189 page ? are you serious ? what are the page content if may i ask !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how to avoid call view method so much times ?

The best solution would be to replace `ViewPager` with `RecyclerView`, so that pages can get recycled.

The next-best solution is to work out some `PagerAdapter` that can manage recycling of your pages.

The solution closest to what you have is:

Step #1: Get rid of `initdata()`

Step #2: Get rid of `pageList()`

Step #3: Inflate the layout and set the text on the `TextView` in `instantiateItem()`, so you only need to do it for pages that the user visits, and then only on demand